# SQL Server matching input and output types of a tabled value function with table valued parameters

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, table-valued-parameters

I'm new to SQL, and I wanted to create functions that do some sort of things on tables.

After a lot of searching, I found out about *table valued functions* and *table valued parameters*.

Here's my example:

```
CREATE TYPE MyType AS TABLE(ID int);   

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc1(@Input MyType READONLY)
RETURNS @Result TABLE(ID int)  
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @Result 
    VALUES(1); --Just a simple example

    RETURN;
END;
```

Everything goes fine with this example, but what if I want to use output of this function for input of another function (such as `MyFunc2`) and do some other things on it?

Surely I can declare a temporary `MyType`, insert values from `MyFunc1` into it and call `MyFunc2` with that temporary variable as input, but what I'm looking for is some sort of pipelining (like streams api in java 8) and I want to call chain of functions, without boilerplate codes between, such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM (MyFunc1(MyFunc2(MyFunc3(@FirstInput, @SecondInput))));
```

How is this possible?

Comment: I don't think this will be possible in T-SQL - there's just no concept of "pipelining". You'll have to do exactly as you mention: define a temporary variable, call `MyFunc1` and get the output into that temporary variable, and then use that as input into `MyFunc2`